# Platform selected at test execution

Tags: testlink

I have a test plan which can be independently applied to two platforms, namely two different servers. Ideally, I would like to be able to select a platform on which a specific test case is ran directly at the test execution stage.

As it stands now, the structure looks like this:

- Platform A

  - Test 1 : Results
  - Test 2 : Results
  - Test 3 : Results
- Platform B

  - Test 1 : Results
  - Test 2 : Results
  - Test 3 : Results

I would like to be able to have something more of that structure:

- Test 1

  - Platform A : Results (if any)
  - Platform B : Results (if any)
- Test 2

  - Platform A : Results (if any)
  - Platform B : Results (if any)

Is there a way to parametrize Testlink to do this rather than completely duplicating the test plan and assign it one different platform each?

Thanks!

Comment: I think customization the report will be the only available option, Please try to customize the report. If you successful, let us know how you did that as well :)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I feared... The other option would be to submit a pull request to the Testlink project to allow this behaviour...!